# How to append incremental id from PHP in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

How can i append `data-item-id` value in `onClick`? I have tried `$(this).data("item-id")` this way but it doesn't return it. Where i am doing wrong?

**JS Code:**

```
$("#tab<?= strtoupper($_GET["tnr"]) ?> .editButton1").append(
    "<img style='width:20px;cursor:pointer' onClick=\"openDialog('edititem'," + $(".editButton").data("item-id") + ")\" src='<?= $global->getImage("edit.png") ?>' title='Protocol Update!' /></a>&nbsp;"
);
```

**PHP Code:**

```
<?php
    foreach ($tickets as $nr => $ticket) {
        ?>
        <tr style="cursor:pointer;" onClick="openDetailDiv('<?= strtoupper(trim($_GET["tnr"])) ?>',<?= $ticket["id"] ?>)">
            <td><?= $ticket["INSDATE"] ?></td>
            <td><?= $ticket["responsible"] ?></td>
            <td class="editButton1">
                <input type='hidden' class='Btn editButton' value='Edit' data-item-id="<?= $ticket['id'] ?>" />
            </td>

        </tr>
    <?php } ?>
```

I want to achieve when anyone click 'edit image' then that `id` details will show details of that `id`.

Comment: make sure click event is working..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To `append` it's much complex and i got a solution without `append` this. Below code is work for me.

```
<?php
foreach ($tickets as $nr => $ticket) {
    ?>
    <tr style="cursor:pointer;" onClick="openDetailDiv('<?= strtoupper(trim($_GET["tnr"])) ?>',<?= $ticket["id"] ?>)">
        <td><?= $ticket["INSDATE"] ?></td>
        <td><?= $ticket["responsible"] ?></td>
        <td class="editButtonMain">
            <img style='width:20px;cursor:pointer' onClick="openDialog('edititem', <?= $ticket['id']?>)" src='<?= $global->getImage("edit.png") ?>' title='Item Update!' />
        </td>

    </tr>
<?php } ?>
```

It may help anyone who looking this type of solution.

Answer (score 0):

You can access an HTML element's dataset like this:

```
document.querySelector('.editButton').dataset.itemId
```

The dataset properties are converted to camelcase format `data-item-id` -> `dataset.itemId`.

Comment: Showing undefined.

Comment: I’m assuming the JS is ran after the PHP has rendered the page?

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the input inside the edit button `<td>`, data attribut is not on `.editButton1` but in the `input` element inside `.editButton1`

```
$(document).on('click', '.editButton1', function(){;
  var itemId = $('[value=Edit]', this).data('item-id');
})
```